# Handling output options in metadata

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I create a new RMarkdown file in RStudio (using latest version of R and RStudio). The header by default is:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "David Arnold"
date: "August 23, 2014"
output: html_document
---
```

Then I go to: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/?version=0.98.1028&mode=desktop

And I view:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
---
```

So I try adding to my header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "David Arnold"
date: "August 23, 2014"
output: html_document:
toc: true
---
```

But now when I use knitHTML to compile, I get the following response:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(front_matter) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4, column 22
Calls: <Anonymous> -> parse_yaml_front_matter -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think indentation is important

Comment: Removing the colon at the end of html_document will remove the error. But to get TOC, you need the indentation as in the second header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the colon (ie. :) after html_document:

Comment: Worked. I also discovered the icon in RStudio that allows the user to make choices without having to type them in. Proper indentation and coding is the result of using this icon.